# Windows 7 desktop.ini shared folder removal script bug

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, desktop.ini

Bit of a batch file question.  I imagine lots of people are having fun with shared folders appearing as "My Documents" in windows explorer.

I look after several schools, where we have the pupil home folders set in a folder called say C:\data\pupils\yeargroup...

The teachers then have access to the pupils folder on a share & can review the pupils work.  With the onset of Windows 7, whereas before Yeargroup folders have had a list of the pupils names with their mydocs inside, you now see a whole load of folders reporting to be "My Documents" due to the desktop.ini located inside of them.

So, I wrote this little batch file & have been running it in `c:\data` on a 15 minute automated task which has done a nice job or restoring law & order:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /s /b /a-d "desktop.ini"') DO attrib -s -h %%i >nul 2>nul
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /s /b /a-d "desktop.ini"') DO del %%i >nul 2>nul
```

The has worked fine up until deployment at a new site that I've just got involved with.  Whereas I set up all folders without spaces:

> C:\data\pupils\yeargroupx\joebloggs

the folder names at this site are something like this:

> C:\data\pupils\yeargroup x\joe bloggs

I have tested running the commands manually & seem to have to run the following (from within the folder location):

1. `dir /ash`
2. `attrib -s -h`
3. `del desktop.ini`

As there are 100s of users, I obviously want to automate this.  Any ideas as to how I would tweak my script?  I want to do `dir /ash` for every folder before I change the attribute of the ini file, otherwise cmd cannot see it.

I got that script running through fudging about rather than any in depth knowledge, so some assistance would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: folder and path names with space(s) must be quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `"%%i"` in the command tails and then spaces and & will not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. The %%i is there but then I'm suppressing  any error messages with >nul 2>nul.  Would you swap these round so %%i comes afterwards?

Comment: Did you notice the quotes surrounding the %%i ?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't.  I'll give this a try.  Will this be necessary for the ones placed before "IF" too?

Comment: Works a treat!  Just on the last bit, so the code now looks as follows:  FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /s /b /a-d "desktop.ini"') DO attrib -s -h "%%i" >nul 2>nul
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /s /b /a-d "desktop.ini"') DO del "%%i" >nul 2>nul